# How to scroll to the end of the list? Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I have a problem with Flutter ListView, When I upload photos to the list I need to scroll to the end, but my code is not working...
what i do:

```
for (var image in _selectedItems){
   // here i deleted some code, but it was Async function like
   // await renderPhoto(image);
   photoHeight += image.height;
}
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 300),(){
    if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0)
          scrollController.animateTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent  + photoHeight,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.easeOut);
});
```

here I get height of all photos and then try to add that to maxScroll position. And That position usually not the end. If i add 1-2 photos it works, but if over 20 - not.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

update:
a few bugs went away when I replaced "animateTo" by "JumpTo".
but I'm still searching

Comment: why are you using ` + photoHeight `on  scrollController.animateTo

Comment: @yeasin-sheikh, I think that when image loading to the List it take some time and maybe the photo will not be added to the list yet. And maxScrollExtent is not max ))

Actually this is a bad approach to do with position of scrollController. 
Someone recommed me to do with Listview.reverse: true, but I can't find some good realization.

Comment: can await to scroll instead of adding photo height, i think `scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent` will animate to bottom

Comment: But how long I need to wait?) If user loading 30 photos with 30mb size or load 1 photo with 1 mb - these are different things.

I think need to think with reverse: true

Comment: okey, i kinda solve this... 
listview -> reverse:true
and data List, which loaded to list -> data.reversed.toList()

Comment: Why do you want to animate to a position where the photos are not loaded / the screen is empty, I think it's better to wait and show a progress indicator during that